# Moving image from mid of screen to corner on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey I'm kind of new to this so forgive me for any obvious mistakes, thanks :)

So I need an image to move from the middle of the screen to the corner of the screen whenever you start scrolling. I was able to get this far. The only problem is that when I scroll back to the top the image doesn't go back to the original spot.

Thanks for any help in advance :)

```js
 window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};
    
    function scrollFunction() {
      if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
        document.getElementById("logo").style.width = "70px";
        document.getElementById("logo").style.margin = "0px";
        document.getElementById("logo").style.position = "fixed";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("logo").style.width = "30%";
        document.getElementById("logo").style.margin = "0 auto";
        document.getElementById("logo").style.position = "relative";
      }
    }
```

```css
#logo {
     width: 30%;
     transition: 0.5s;
     margin: 0 auto;
     margin-top: 15%;
    }
    
    
    .scroll {
     height: 1200px;
    }
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/siu5pjx.css">
    </head>     
<body>
    
    <!--LOGO-->
    <div id="logo">
     <a href="<?php echo get_page_link( get_page_by_title( home )->ID ); ?>">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" width="100%">
     </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="scroll"></div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seemed to work on when I tested it... not sure what the problem is?

Answer (score 3):

So the problem is that when you scroll back up, you are not adding in the `margin`.

This can be simply fixed by adding re-adding the margin with javascript.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};
    
    function scrollFunction() {
      if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
        document.getElementById("logo").style.width = "70px";
        document.getElementById("logo").style.margin = "0px";
        document.getElementById("logo").style.position = "fixed";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("logo").style.width = "30%";
        document.getElementById("logo").style.margin = "0 auto";
        document.getElementById("logo").style.marginTop = "15%";
        document.getElementById("logo").style.position = "relative";
      }
    }
```

```css
#logo {
     width: 30%;
     transition: 0.5s;
     margin: 0 auto;
     margin-top: 15%;
    }
    
    
    .scroll {
     height: 1200px;
    }
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/siu5pjx.css">
    </head>     
<body>
    
    <!--LOGO-->
    <div id="logo">
     <a href="<?php echo get_page_link( get_page_by_title( home )->ID ); ?>">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" width="100%">
     </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="scroll"></div>  
</body>
</html>
```